# Having problem to comparing case sensitive strings in Linq entities to PostgreSQL

Tags: entity-framework, .net-4.8

I'm currently working on a .Net Framework(4.7.2) project using PostgreSQL, which supports case sensitivity. While I've managed case sensitivity on the database side, I need a global solution for handling case sensitivity in LINQ queries without using ToLower()/ToUpper(). The client doesn't want to change existing code, making it crucial to find a seamless, global solution for this requirement.

below is a customer table

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Anish |
| 2 | Sharma |

When we are trying to compare below query getting null value.

```cs
var data=db.Customers.Where(x => x.Name == "anish").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This is totally correct behavior (for most default DB collations), "Anish" != "anish" as long as the collation on your column/table/DB is not case-insensitive. You'll need to research case-insensitive string comparison for EF and Postgres as the solutions are generally DB provider specific.

Comment: The duplicate is the opposite, but what matters is that the database collation determines everything and there are fine explanations in the best answers.

Comment: Have you tried using EF.Functions.Collate in your EF query and selecting a collation that is case insensitive?

Comment: I'm currently working on a project using PostgreSQL, which supports case sensitivity. While I've managed case sensitivity on the database side, I need a global solution for handling case sensitivity in LINQ queries without using ToLower()/ToUpper(). The client doesn't want to change existing code, making it crucial to find a seamless, global solution for this requirement.

Comment: Without changing code? I don't understand. Anyway, this is impossible. The database collation has the casting vote in comparisons being case sensitive or not. If they don't want to change collations, all that's left is meddling with `ToLower` etc. (or do comparison client-side, but it can't get worse than that). In EF core (which you don't use) you can tack this `EF.Functions.Collate` onto all string comparisons, but that's not necessarily better. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/collations-and-case-sensitivity